# C++ __usercall hooking

Tags: c++, assembly, wrapper, reverse-engineering, usercall

Hello in IDA i have a function

```
void __userpurge Test(int a1<eax>, int a2, int a3, int a4, char a5)
```

And i would like to hook/call it from my C++ injected dll
This is how I have tried to call it but .exe crashes

```
DWORD CALL_ORIGINAL = 0x00EAF6D0;
__declspec(naked) void  myHookedFunc(int a1,int a2,int a3,int a4,char a5) {
    __asm
 {

    push a5
    push a4
    push a3
    push a2
    push eax
    call  CALL_ORGIGINAL //maybe use JMP?
    retn

   }
}
```

And this is how the exe calls this function

```
mov     eax, [ebp+arg_4]
add     esp, 8
push    eax
push    ecx
mov     ecx, [edi+2138h]
mov     edx, [ecx+4]
mov     ecx, [edx+30h]
mov     edx, [ecx]
mov     eax, esp
mov     [eax], edx
mov     eax, [edi+20h]
mov     [esp+40h+var_24], esp
push    eax
push    eax
mov     eax, edi
call    Test
pop     edi
pop     esi  
retn
```

Few times in function there appears to be

```
add     esp, 24h
retn    10h
```

Which would mean there are more arguments or IDA got wrong argument types?

Comment: Don't trust the signature of function from IDA. Some time, IDA do not produces the proper signature. You need to analyze it manually.

Answer (score 2):

`__userpurge` functions use a calling convention similar to `__usercall` except that the caller is responsible for cleaning up the stack. However looking at the additional code you have posted IDA may very well be providing an incorrect number of parameters *and* an incorrect calling convention. I suggest that you verify this by placing a breakpoint at the location of `call  CALL_ORGIGINAL` and watch the value of ESP before and after the call. If ESP is different when it returns then `CALL_ORIGINAL` is cleaning up the stack and there is nothing more for you to do. If `CALL_ORIGINAL` does clean up the stack you can likely determine the number of parameters passed by dividing the difference by 4 (assuming each parameter is 32bits).

Another problem is you should not be pushing `eax` onto the stack (according to the calling code included in your edit). The existing code that calls this function places the first parameter in `eax` but does not push it onto the stack.

Based on the code in your question and assuming the number of parameters is correct your hook function should look something like the example below.

```
__declspec(naked) void  myHookedFunc(int a1,int a2,int a3,int a4,char a5) {
    __asm
 {

    push a5
    push a4
    push a3
    push a2
    // eax is not pushed onto the stack
    call CALL_ORGIGINAL
    retn
   }
}
```

If the calling convention and number of parameters is correct ESP should be the same value before and after the all to `CALL_ORIGINAL`. If it's not you will need to investigate it a bit more to determine the correct calling convention and parameters.

In short, **never** trust what IDA unless you verify it yourself.

Comment: A couple of times in function there is
add     esp, 24h
retn    10h

So i guess there is more arguments and IDA is wrong?

Comment: @user1422473 That's a good assumption. I've edited my answer to reflect the additional code you posted. Pay attention to the lines AFTER the `call Test` to make sure you are cleaning up the stack properly. If you can include the code after the call I will update my answer if necessary.

Comment: I checked the function and first line of it is sub     esp, 24h
which means it cleans up the stack itself